# How to target the last column in a CSS grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

When you use `grid-areas` the elements may change order. This will cause the visual `:last-child` to change. Is there a CSS selector to target the last column in a grid instead? Something like `:last-grid-column`.

The problem I am trying to solve. I like the columns to be separated by a border line. However I don't want the last column to have a border, because that wouldn't make visually sense. Now if I were to target it with `:last-child` it works until I change the order of the `grid-template-areas` to something like `d b c a`. Now the first column would not have a border because in the DOM it's still the last-child.

I understand you can have a work around where you would explicitly say these are the grid areas and I would omit the border for `a` in this case. But it would be so much more flexible if I could describe it semantically, then I could freely change the template areas without worrying that the border lines will be messed up.

```css
.grid 
{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "d b c a";
  grid-template-columns: repeat( 4, 1fr );
}

.column.a { 
  grid-area: a; 
}

.column.b { 
  grid-area: b; 
}

.column.c { 
  grid-area: c; 
}

.column.d { 
  grid-area: d; 
}

.column:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

/* Flavor */
.grid 
{
  margin: 20px auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #F4F4F4;
}

.column { 
  width: 100%; 
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="column a">A</div>
  <div class="column b">B</div>
  <div class="column c">C</div>
  <div class="column d">D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be easier to help and provide a working code example if you include sample html/css/js in your question.

Comment: I replaced the large text with code now.

Comment: In order to do what?

Comment: Woops, I accidently removed the problem part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such [selector exist](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#table-pseudos) but we are still far from having a good support for it. You can read:

> To be able to represent such implied column-based relationships, the column combinator and the :nth-col() and :nth-last-col() pseudo-classes are defined

For your particular case, a background can do the job:

```css
.grid 
{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "d b c a";
  grid-template-columns: repeat( 4, 1fr );
  background:
    linear-gradient(90deg,#0000 calc(100% - 1px), #000 0)
    0 50%/calc((100% + 1px)/4) 50% repeat-x
    #F4F4F4;
}

.column.a { 
  grid-area: a; 
}

.column.b { 
  grid-area: b; 
}

.column.c { 
  grid-area: c; 
}

.column.d { 
  grid-area: d; 
}


/* Flavor */
.grid 
{
  margin: 20px auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.column { 
  width: 100%; 
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="column a">A</div>
  <div class="column b">B</div>
  <div class="column c">C</div>
  <div class="column d">D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good catch and the answer to the question. (https://css4-selectors.com/selector/css4/grid-structural-pseudo-class/)

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this problem is to show the border with each column and hide the border of the last column using a pseudo-element on the container element with the following CSS:

```
.grid::after {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   width: 20px;
   right: 0;
   height: 100%;
   background: #F4F4F4;
}
```

Trick here is to have the pseudo-element be of the same color as the container `.grid` element and its width to be equal to the padding of the `.grid` element.

To make this solution more maintainable, you could use CSS variables for `padding` and `background-color` of the `.grid` element.

#### Demo

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "d c b a";
  grid-template-columns: repeat( 4, 1fr);
  margin: 20px auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #F4F4F4;
  position: relative;
}

.column.a {
  grid-area: a;
}

.column.b {
  grid-area: b;
}

.column.c {
  grid-area: c;
}

.column.d {
  grid-area: d;
}

.column {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.grid::after {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   width: 20px;
   right: 0;
   height: 100%;
   background: #F4F4F4;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="column a">A</div>
  <div class="column b">B</div>
  <div class="column c">C</div>
  <div class="column d">D</div>
</div>
```

Here's the previous demo with some Javascript to allow changing the `grid-template-areas` property dynamically.

```js
const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");
const btn = document.querySelector("button");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  grid.classList.toggle("change-column-order");
});
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "a b c d";
  grid-template-columns: repeat( 4, 1fr);
  margin: 20px auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #F4F4F4;
  position: relative;
}

.column.a {
  grid-area: a;
}

.column.b {
  grid-area: b;
}

.column.c {
  grid-area: c;
}

.column.d {
  grid-area: d;
}

.column {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.grid::after {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   width: 20px;
   right: 0;
   height: 100%;
   background: #F4F4F4;
}

.change-column-order {
  grid-template-areas: "d c b a";
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="column a">A</div>
  <div class="column b">B</div>
  <div class="column c">C</div>
  <div class="column d">D</div>
</div>

<button>Change Column Order</button>
```

Comment: So that would confirm there is no such css selector. Sneaky work around though, well done.

Comment: AFAIK, no. There is `:last-child` but, as you already know, it won't help in your case.