# CSS grid: Find last item of each row

Tags: css, css-grid, responsive

I've got a simple grid with auto-fit columns. So depending on the available screen width one, two, three or more items get displayed in a row.

The challange: The last item of each row should always be styled different. Can this be achieved out-of-the-box with css grid or do I need media queries for that?

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
   <div>Item 1</div>
   <div>Item 2</div>
   <div>Item 3</div>
   <div>Item 4</div>
   <div>Item 5</div>
   <div>Item 6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'd need MQ or JS for that. CSS doesn't "know" which element is last on a row,

Comment: What sort of styling do you need. Sometimes background color for example can be achieved through positioning, but more complex stuff would need calculation.

Comment: @AHaworth  I am placing a vertical divider between each item using :after but on the last item of each row there should not be one

Comment: better update your question with that requirement because we can do the divider thing without the need to know the last item

Comment: here is how: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56012789/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif The solution uses overflow:hidden which is in my opinion not very elegant as it can cause trouble down the line. My question is more of a general nature since I've implemented the desired design using media queries already. I wanted to simplify it though.

Comment: then the answer to your generic question is a No. You still need to wait to have such selector: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68756301/8620333

Comment: For the specific 'hide last vertical bar' you could probably overlay it with a white (for example) pseudo element on the parent - but not sure it's worth it.